# Angular call to PHP returns 404 after Grunt build

Tags: php, angularjs, gruntjs, restful-url, mamp-pro

Really hope someone will point me in the right direction, I'm lost :D Building my first ng-app, and the Grunt build results in api calls (php) not being found.

Folder structure is dist->api->index.php, so I'm not sure why the calls return 404.

I have MAMP as a server, and the calls look like they contain the entire path: `http://disty:8888/api/testimonials`

With grunt-serve in dev, I used a different port and not MAMP, but to my knowledge that has nothing to do with production, right?

This is probably nothing, but I'm very much hoping to learn. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grunt-serve can't serve PHP files, if you want to create PHP server replace grunt-serve with [grunt-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-php) and configure a **base** and **port**.

It should be configured like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
php: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            port: 8888,
            base: 'dist/api/',
            keepalive: true,
            open: true
        }
    }
}
});
```

After this you should have got an access to your index.php API.